# Extracting counts of contiguous zeros and ones from a binary array

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, histograms

I'm a novice with *Mathematica*, but you guys have been very helpful to me in the past. I have a binary array [100, J repetitions] consisting of zeroes and ones. I'd like to extract a histogram of the number of contiguous ones in these individual columns.

Assuming I have some variable `f[i, j]` containing these data what I have is:

```
Do[
  bhist = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 0, {1, 100}, 0]; 
  index = 1; 
  Do[If[f[[j, i]] == 1, index++, bhist[[index]] + 1; index = 1], 
    {i, 1, 100}]; 
  bhista[j] = bhist;, 
  {j, 1, rep}];
```

where `bhist` will record the number of contiguous 1s and how many times that ensemble occurs.  This will loop over all j repetitions of the monte carlo.

The problem is that I seem to only be generating zeroes despite the fact that my simulation does generate contiguous 1s.  Is my `If` expression setting the index to 1 before it records the value in my `bhist` variable? Or is something else going on?

Furthermore, if I wanted to then extract a histogram from `bhista`, is there a more efficient way of doing this than flattening it and bin counting?

Comment: Have you seen for example `Split` and `Tally`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hint. Say you have a vector:

```
x = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}
```

This has one triplet and two doublets and one single 1. This information can be extracted:

```
Length /@ Select[Split[x], Total[#] > 0 &]
```

which gives

```
{3, 2, 2, 1}
```

Now you can apply this to each column of the data matrix.

Comment: You beat me. :-)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard -- But yours has a pretty picture!

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not positive that I follow what you're attempting, but I strongly suspect that belisarius's recommendation is correct.  Perhaps this is close enough to what you want:

```
SeedRandom[3]; (* for consistency *)

a = RandomInteger[1, {100}];

Cases[Split[a], {1, ___}] // Tally // Sort
```

> ```
> {{{1}, 12}, {{1, 1}, 5}, {{1, 1, 1}, 3}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, 3}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 1}}
> ```

```
Labeled[#2, Length@#] & @@@ % // BarChart
```

[image]